# Don`t insert at postgreSQL

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, ethereum, typeorm

I have a problem. I'm trying insert value on table, but he don't insert

```
    const oldBlockNumber = await this.walletForCheckRepository.createQueryBuilder().getOne();
    await this.walletForCheckRepository
    .createQueryBuilder()
      .update()
      .set({ block_number: newBlockNumber })
      .where('block_number =:block_number', { block_number: oldBlockNumber })
      .execute();
  }
```

And I have error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'block_number' of undefined

I use postgreSQL, NestJS, typeorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the TypeORM model to the `update()` function. See the [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/update-query-builder) for more info.

So if your model containing the property `block_number` is named `MyModel`, your code is going to be

```
.update(MyModel)
```

instead of

```
.update()
```

Comment: I need do

```const blockNumber = block_number
 await this.walletForCheckRepository
    .createQueryBuilder()
      .update(blockNumber)
```?

Comment: Not `.update(blockNumber)` (which is btw undefined in the context of your question) as your comment suggests - you need to pass the **model**.

Comment: ```@Entity('last_block')
export default class LastBlockEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  block_number: number;
}
```

I added in model, but still this error

Comment: It seems that your model is also misconfigured. Please post a separate question if you need help with the model configuration, because there isn't much space to solve it in the comments.